# How can I make my bot respond on reactions?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm currently trying to make a ticket system on my bot with reactions, it shows no error but when I react it won't give out the "Hi" output, my code is the following:

```
client.on("ready", async () => {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("my server ID")
  const channel = guild.channels.cache.get("the channel ID")
  const message = guild.channels.cache.get("the same channel ID").send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor("Tickets", guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })).setDescription("React to the emoji below to start a ticket")).then(sent => {
    sent.react("✉️")
  const filter = (r, u) => r.emoji.name === "✉️";
  const collector = sent.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 1 });
  collector.on("collect", (r, u) => {
    if(u.bot) return null;
    else channel.send("Hi")
  })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the bot won't respond is that it has already collected the ✉️ in the message from the bot itself, thus it has reached its `max` of 1 reaction. But it checks that `u.bot` is indeed `true` (in the `collect` event), and thus will not respond at all.

To fix this, you can remove `if(u.bot) return null;` inside of the collection event, and put it in the `filter` instead, like this:

```js
const filter = (r, u) => r.emoji.name === "✉️" && !u.bot;
```